# babel + hyperref: »redefining shorthand« several times per page

Tags: hyperref, babel, logging

consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext
\Blindtext\Blindtext\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

...and a small piece from its logfile.

```
[3]
Package babel Info: Redefining ngerman shorthand "|
(babel)             in language  on input line 7.
Package babel Info: Redefining ngerman shorthand "~
(babel)             in language  on input line 7.
Package babel Info: Redefining ngerman shorthand "|
(babel)             in language  on input line 7.
Package babel Info: Redefining ngerman shorthand "~
(babel)             in language  on input line 7.
Package babel Info: Redefining ngerman shorthand "|
(babel)             in language  on input line 7.
Package babel Info: Redefining ngerman shorthand "~
(babel)             in language  on input line 7.
```

babel seems to redefine these shorthands several times per page, even when there's nothing but plain text (why does it do so?). This happens only if `hyperref` is active. Half of that logfile consists of nothing but iterations of these lines. Obviously, it's even worse in the 350-page document that I'm currently working on, making troubleshooting a real pain in the neck. Is there a way to prevent this bloating?

Comment: Unfortunately, the `silence` package doesn't provide for silencing Info messages.

Comment: no even disabling hyperref'ing with `draft` mode silences it :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The info comes from `\pdfstringdef`, which is used to convert a TeX string to a PDF bookmark string. `\pdfstringdef` redefines many, many commands to disable them, to provide replacements. Thus `hyperref` also redefines some shorthands. For example, TeX's hyphenation is irrelevant for bookmarks, thus `hyperref` redefines the shorthands for `ngerman` regarding hyphenation:

```
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"|}{}%
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"~}{-}%
```

Two info messages are generated, each time `\pdfstringdef` is invoked with `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`. This happens for `\section` and friends and some other occasions (setting of PDF information entries).

Comment: The babel shorthand macro `"|` is not so much about hyphenation as it is about ligature suppression. Does the disabling of this macro in PDF bookmarks mean that words such as `auf"|fliegen` will get typeset with an `ffl` ligature in the bookmarks? Or is it the case that ligatures are disabled anyway in bookmarks and hence that it's not necessary to suppress them in the first place?

Comment: The TeX setting engine is not available for bookmarks. Ligatures are a property of the TFM (TeX Font Metrics) data. But the bookmark strings are just simple text strings without any font setting. If you want to have a ligature, you have to set it explicitly (with Unicode encoding).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Wouldn't disable `\bbl@info` when doing `\pdfstringdef` be a good idea?

Comment: @egreg I do not know. It is not a bug to have a correct information message. Thus the main question is about the purpose of the message, why it exists in the first place. BTW, `\bbl@info` cannot be disabled via `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands`, because `\declare@shorthand` is used *before* the user addistions by `\pdfstringdefDisableCommand`.

Comment: The information is correct, but in this case very annoying and I'd say useless, in this case. Check the patch I propose, that is, adding `\let\bbl@info\@gobble` before doing `\csname HyPsd@babel@\language@group\endcsname`.

Comment: thanks egreg and Heiko for your replies. I'd like to emphasize that I don't question the usefulness of that message -- what I'm interested in (besides ways of silencing it) is why all that defining and redefining is going on in the first place (even without `\section` and friends). My concern, ultimately, is processing time, i.e. the question of how much faster would a TeX run be without these things.

Comment: @NilsL This includes the page number, which is displayed as PDF page label, a plain PDF string without TeX typesetting. Regarding optimization: Some of hyperref's features can be disabled, use of package hyperref can be removed. Plain TeX instead of LaTeX can be used, At last, you get a very fast processing time without any text and contents.

Comment: *> without any text and contents*

...that's what I've been trying to convince my PhD supervisor of for ages! Good to hear I'm not the only one thinking that's a good idea `:)`

Answer (score 12):

Once you know that such information is irrelevant (and it is), you can use gentle manners (also known as “the sledgehammer”) to silence it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@decl@short}{\bbl@info}{\@gobble}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@decl@short}{\bbl@info}{\@gobble}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-40]
\end{document}
```

No more `Redefining ngerman shorthand` message.

A more delicate patch would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\pdfstringdef}
  {\csname HyPsd@babel@}
  {\let\bbl@info\@gobble\csname HyPsd@babel@}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-40]

\end{document}
```

that would disable `\bbl@info` (when redefining shorthands) only in the context of `\pdfstringdef`.

Comment: This is a relief! These messages were driving me crazy :-)

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Another strategy is giving up writing in German. `;-)`

Comment: With all that package documenting in English, I think I'm approximating to that final goal ;-)

Comment: works great; just reduced my log file from 10000 to 2000 lines. Thanks!